# Draw on TeeChart directly with GDI+

Tags: delphi, gdi+, teechart

How to rotate and draw a transperent PNG image using GDI+ directly on TChart?

Currently I load PNG image to a bitmap and use two bitmaps for GDI+ rotation (it works very fast) and then make the target bitmap transparent and draw it on TChart's canvas (it works slow when transparency is on).

```
procedure TPitchDisplay._chartAfterDraw(Sender: TObject);
var
  c: TCanvas3D;
  pw, ph: Integer;
  r: TRect;
  bmp: TBitmap;
  rotAngle: Integer;
begin
  _setKnobBounds();
  c := _chart.Canvas;
  _drawCircle(c, _knob.CenterPoint.X, _knob.CenterPoint.Y, Round(_knob.YRadius * 0.9));
  c.StretchDrawQuality := sqHigh;
  pw := 450;
  ph := Round((pw / _shipBitmap.Width) * _shipBitmap.Height);
  r.Left := _chart.ChartXCenter - pw div 2;
  r.Top := Round(_chart.Height / 3);
  r.Width := pw;
  r.Height := ph;

  //Draw water
  c.StretchDraw(Rect(0, r.Top + Round(ph / 1.5), _chart.Width, _chart.Height), _waterBitmap);

  //Draw rotated ship over it
  bmp := TBitmap.Create();
  try
    bmp.Width := Round(_shipBitmap.Width * 1.2);
    bmp.Height := Round(_shipBitmap.Height * 1.7);
    bmp.TransparentColor := clBlack;
    bmp.Transparent := True;
    bmp.TransparentMode := TTransparentMode.tmFixed;
    if VarIsNumeric(_pitchBox.Value) then
      rotAngle := _pitchBox.Value
    else
      rotAngle := 0;
    TGraphUtils.RotateBitmap(_shipBitmap, bmp, 0.5, 0.7, rotAngle, False, clBlack);
    c.StretchDraw(r, bmp);
  finally
    bmp.Free();
  end;
end;
```

Rotation routine:

```
class procedure TGraphUtils.RotateBitmap(srcBmp, tgtBmp: TBitmap; rotateAtX, rotateAtY: Single; Degs: Integer; AdjustSize: Boolean;
  BkColor: TColor = clNone);
var
  Tmp: TGPBitmap;
  Matrix: TGPMatrix;
  C: Single;
  S: Single;
  NewSize: TSize;
  Graphs: TGPGraphics;
  P: TGPPointF;
  attr: TGPImageAttributes;
begin
  Tmp := TGPBitmap.Create(srcBmp.Handle, srcBmp.Palette);
  Matrix := TGPMatrix.Create();
  try
    Matrix.RotateAt(Degs, MakePoint(rotateAtX * srcBmp.Width, rotateAtY * srcBmp.Height));
    if AdjustSize then begin
      C := Cos(DegToRad(Degs));
      S := Sin(DegToRad(Degs));
      NewSize.cx := Round(srcBmp.Width * Abs(C) + srcBmp.Height * Abs(S));
      NewSize.cy := Round(srcBmp.Width * Abs(S) + srcBmp.Height * Abs(C));
      tgtBmp.Width := NewSize.cx;
      tgtBmp.Height := NewSize.cy;
    end;
    Graphs := TGPGraphics.Create(tgtBmp.Canvas.Handle);
    attr := TGPImageAttributes.Create;
    try
      Graphs.Clear(ColorRefToARGB(ColorToRGB(BkColor)));
      Graphs.SetTransform(Matrix);
      //attr.SetColorKey($FFFFFF {TGPColor.Blue}, $FFFFFF {TGPColor.Blue}, ColorAdjustTypeBitmap);
      Graphs.DrawImage(Tmp, (Cardinal(tgtBmp.Width) - Tmp.GetWidth) div 2,
        (Cardinal(tgtBmp.Height) - Tmp.GetHeight) div 2);
    finally
      attr.Free();
      Graphs.Free();
    end;
  finally
    Matrix.Free();
    Tmp.Free();
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1AfterDraw(Sender: TObject);
var
  GPImage: TGPImage;
  GPGraphics: TGPGraphics;
  Matrix: TGPMatrix;
  c: TCanvas3d;
 begin
  c := Chart1.Canvas;
  GPImage := TGPImage.Create('e:\2.png');
  GPGraphics :=  TGPGraphics.Create(C.Handle);
  Matrix := TGPMatrix.Create;
  Matrix.Rotate(30);
  Matrix.Scale(0.5, 0.5);
  GPGraphics.SetTransform(Matrix);
  GPGraphics.DrawImage(GPImage, 150, 0);
  Matrix.Free;
  GPGraphics.Free;
  GPimage.Free;
end;
```

Not precise example of output into form center:

```
  IM := TGPMatrix.Create;
  IM := Matrix.Clone;
  IM.Invert;
  pc := MakePoint(Width div 2 - GPImage.GetWidth() div 2, 
                  Height div 2 - Integer(GPImage.GetHeight) div 2);
  Im.TransformPoints(pgppoINT(@pc));
  GPGraphics.DrawImage(GPImage, pc);
```

Comment: It works, and very fast! Thank you. Probably you could give me an idea how to load TGPImage from PNG resource? I was using TPNGImage to load it to a bitmap.

Comment: I changed `Matrix.Rotate(30)` in your example to `Matrix.RotateAt(rotAngle, MakePoint(GPImage.GetWidth() div 2, GPImage.GetHeight() div 2))` to rotate around image center, and it rotates properly, but when I change in `GPGraphics.DrawImage(GPImage, 150, 0)` the `150` to `_chart.ChartXCenter`, it rotates around the image corner again. I don't have an idea why.

Comment: Does ResourceStream/StreamAdapter/IStream/TGPImage.FromStream approach work for png?

Comment: It rotates around image center but ouput occurs in rotated coordinate system (try drawimage with y=0 and different x, and you'll see image shifts by inclined line). You have to find coordinates of chart center in new coordinate system (using inverse matrix). I've added rough example

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It helped just to use `Matrix.Translate(x,y)` BEFORE RotateAt to shift an image.